# Jquery validate pattern method stops validation of other fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the Jquery Validate plugin along with the additional methods for client side validation of my form. Everything works great so far, I just have one problem. When I use the one of the additional methods to validate it against, if that one fails then it does not continue to validate any other fields.

So currently I leave a form blank and hit submit I see a list of all the errors. But if I input numbers in a name field and hit submit then I see only one error for the failed pattern rule. Here is my jquery:

```
$j("#wizardForm").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+([\s]+)?[']?([a-zA-Z]+)?$/
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+([\s]+)?[']?([a-zA-Z]+)?$/
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: "required",
        PWconfirm: "required",
        country: "required"
    },
    errorLabelContainer: ".validation-error-msg",
    wrapper: "li",
    errorClass: "validation-error",
    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: "The 'First Name' field cannot be empty.",
            pattern: "The first name field must only contain letters."
        },
        lastname: {
            required: "The 'Last Name' field cannot be empty.",
            pattern: "The 'Last Name' field must only contain letters."
        },
        email: {
            required: "The 'Email Address' field cannot be empty.",
            email: "The email address must be in a valid email format."
        },
        password: "The 'Password' field cannot be empty.",
        PWconfirm: "The 'Retype Password' field cannot be empty.",
        country: "The 'Country' field needs a valid selection."
    }
});
```

Is there a way I can allow it to show all errors when a rule from the additional methods fails?

Comment: There is nothing special about the `additional-methods` file or anything contained within that causes the problem you describe.  It's just a list of methods.  Please show the relevant HTML markup so I can reproduce.  As it stands, the code you've shown does not demonstrate what you describe.  All errors remain:  http://jsfiddle.net/07jm89wp/

Comment: Although you've used the `pattern` rule on the **last** name field, while you've defined its custom message on the **first** name field, that wouldn't normally break anything either.

Comment: @Sparky I have edited the code to include the pattern method on both firstname and lastname fields. I took your jsfiddel and pasted the code I have above into it and was able to reproduce the problem by entering '123' in the first name field, or entering '123' in the last name field while leaving the first name field blank. It shows only a single error instead of the list of all errors. http://jsfiddle.net/07jm89wp/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wrapper` option is breaking it.  Probably because you're trying to create `<li>` elements outside of a `<ul>` container.  Reading [the docs for `wrapper`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#wrapper)...

> Wrap error labels with the specified element. **Useful in combination with `errorLabelContainer` to create a list of error messages**.

But you're not creating a *"list of error messages"*; you're creating messages inline, so `wrapper` and `errorLabelContainer` are pointless in this demo.

Working otherwise:  http://jsfiddle.net/07jm89wp/3/

Comment: I really appreciate your help. That does work if I'm not creating a list of errors. But if I were to create a list of errors as that was my ultimate goal once I got this issues figured out, how would I go about it? Leaving the `errorLabelContainer` in without the `wrapper` option still gives the same problem when creating a list. Here is a fiddle with the container added so the errors are no longer inline. http://jsfiddle.net/07jm89wp/4/

Comment: @Jmh2013, you're following the example in the docs and it's still broken.  I believe you've found a bug in the plugin and should report it to the developer on his GitHub page:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Comment: I have submitted an issue on his GitHub page. You did answer the original question though. Thank you! Here is a link to the reported issue if you are interested. https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1480